# VBA Excel Unfiltering but not unhiding rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a code to filter certain data and copy it. After which, I want to unfilter it to its original state. I am using the ActiveSheet.ShowAllData statement but that unhides all the hidden rows as well. Is there a set of code that allows me to unfilter my filtered data but not unhide any rows that were previously hidden?

Thanks for answering

EDIT: This is the code if it helps.

Sub CopyToAmortizing()

```
Dim tbl As Range
Dim VisibleCells As Integer
Dim lr As Long

Sheets("Template").Select
Columns("A:AZ").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
If Not ActiveSheet.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then Cells.AutoFilter
Range("A5:AB5").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Set tbl = Selection

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$N$9999").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "Amortizing Item"
```

On Error GoTo Point2

```
VisibleCells = tbl.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
If VisibleCells >= 1 Then

Range("A3").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Activate
lr = ActiveCell.Row

Range("B3", Cells(lr, 12)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("AmortizingItems").Select
Range("A2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Rows(2).EntireRow.Delete
Range("A2").Select
Sheets("Template").Select
End If
```

Point2:

```
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
Columns("A:AZ").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1
Range("A5").Select
```

End Sub

I use filter: 
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$N$9999").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "Amortizing Item"
And then: ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

Comment: Can you post the current code you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy answer is to turn off AutoFilter by using

```
Sheets("YourSheetName").AutoFilterMode = False
```

Here is a sample where I add the hidden rows to an array, then re-hide after I am done with them...

```
Sub SampleHiddenRows()

Set hidrows = New Collection

Set Rng = Range(Cells(5, 4), Cells(13, 5))

For Each cll In Rng
    If cll.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
        hidrows.Add cll.Row
    End If
Next cll

Rng.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="one"
Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy


ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

For t = 1 To hidrows.Count
    Rows(hidrows(t)).Hidden = True
Next t

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this for a set of filtered data including a hidden row, and the above line unhid the row when the filter was removed.

Comment: @davidmneedham Thanks! I did as your answer by setting a new collection and adding hidden rows to the collection then re-hide them at the end. Works well!